# Extracting data from a variable in form of html

Tags: javascript

I requested data from server and got in the form of

```
 <tr>
    <td style='text-align:center;' sorttable_customkey='0'>
        <div ID='greencir' class='colcir' title='Online now'></div>
    </td>
    <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='1' title='Leader'>Leader</td>
    <td class='playerblink allymemtoolt' title='abc'>abc</td>
    <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='7' title='king'>king</td>
    <td class='allymemtoolt sorttable_numeric' style='text-align:center;' title='17'>17</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style='text-align:center;' sorttable_customkey='1'>
        <div ID='greycir' class='colcir' title='Offline'></div>
    </td>
    <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='2' title='Second Leader'>Second Leader</td>
    <td class='playerblink allymemtoolt' title='xy'>xy</td>
    <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='7' title='slave'>slave</td>
    <td class='allymemtoolt sorttable_numeric' style='text-align:center;' title='13'>13</td>
</tr>
```

how do I extract the title's from the td, since its not in the DOM .children() is not working

Comment: put your javascript code here

Comment: jquery will do it easy, append to your page and will work very easy with your DOM

Comment: *DOM .children() is not working* - can you show your effort? Also, elaborate should it be the titles of <td> tags directly OR the titles of <td> children elements?

Answer (score 0):

Well if that response was saved in a variable `res` then you would just give that to jquery and parse it as such. i.e. something like

```
$(res).find("tr").each(function(v,k) { $(v).attr("title") })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is not in the DOM, then You can try the below solution:

```
 var tblData='<table>'+yourDataVariable+'</table>'
 $(tblData).find("tr").each(function(){
   console.log($(this).find("td").attr("title"));
 });
```

You will see all the title in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got that data from the server, I assume you have that as an AJAX response. If I am right, then you can have a tag like this:

```
<div id="foobar"></div>
```

and you can set its inner HTML like this:

```
document.getElementById("foobar").innerHTML = yourResponse;
```

and after that you can read the `td` elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll("td div[title]")
```

where you specify that you are interested in `div` elements having a `title` inside `td` elements.

Comment: I dont have a tag if div in that response, only what I showed above plus 70 more like those, its a response going to a table

Comment: @Cooldeveloper I did not assume you had. I have shown you could create it. You could use your table if you do not like the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find element in html string and [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get values from array of element found using your selector please find below snippet for more information

```js
debugger;
var dynamichtml =" <tr> <td style='text-align:center;' sorttable_customkey='0'> <div ID='greencir' class='colcir' title='Online now'></div> </td> <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='1' title='Leader'>Leader</td> <td class='playerblink allymemtoolt' title='abc'>abc</td> <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='7' title='king'>king</td> <td class='allymemtoolt sorttable_numeric' style='text-align:center;' title='17'>17</td></tr><tr> <td style='text-align:center;' sorttable_customkey='1'> <div ID='greycir' class='colcir' title='Offline'></div> </td> <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='2' title='Second Leader'>Second Leader</td> <td class='playerblink allymemtoolt' title='xy'>xy</td> <td class='allymemtoolt' sorttable_customkey='7' title='slave'>slave</td> <td class='allymemtoolt sorttable_numeric' style='text-align:center;' title='13'>13</td></tr>"

var found = $(dynamichtml).find(".colcir");
var titleattr = jQuery.map( found, function( a ) {
  return $(a).attr("title");
});

console.log(titleattr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get attribute value by this way: `document.querySelector('#yourID').getAttribute('yourAttribute')`